# Layering density plots in R without using density()

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice, kernel-density

I've computed and plotted gaussian kernel density estimates using the KernSmooth package as follows:

```
 x <- MyData$MyNumericVector
 h <- dpik(x)
 est <- bkde(x, bandwidth=h)
 plot(est, type='l')
```

This is the method described in KernSmooth's documentation. Note that `dpik()` finds the optimal bandwidth and `bkde()` uses this bandwidth to fit the kernel density estimate.  It's important that I use this method instead of the basic `density()` function.

How do I layer these plots on top of one another?

I cannot use the basic `density()` function that `geom_density()` from `ggplot2` relies upon, as bandwidths and kernel density estimates are best optimized using the KernSmooth package (see Deng & Wickham, 2011 here: http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/density-estimation.pdf). Since Wickham wrote `ggplot2` and the above review of kernel density estimation packages, it would make sense that there's a way to use `ggplot2` to layer densities that aren't reliant on the basic `density()` function, but I'm not sure.

Can I use `ggplot2` for this even if I don't wish to use the basic `density()` function?  What about `lattice` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with `geom_line`:

```
 m <- ggplot(NULL, aes(x=bkde(movies$votes)$x,y=bkde(movies$votes)$y)) + geom_line()
 print(m)
```

If you were doing t with lattice::densityplot, you could probably add some of the values to the drags-list:

> darg
>   list of arguments to be passed to the density function. Typically, this should be a list with zero or more of the following components : bw, adjust, kernel, window, width, give.Rkern, n, from, to, cut, na.rm (see density for details)

Comment: For those who are interested, here's how the code turned out: `ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x = bkde(MyFirstDataframe$MyNumericVector, bandwidth = h)$x, y = bkde(MyFirstDataframe$MyNumericVector, bandwidth = h)$y)) + geom_line(aes(x = bkde(MySecondDataframe$MyNumericVector, bandwidth = h)$x, y = bkde(MySecondDataframe$MyNumericVector, bandwidth = h)$y))`